# Replicate Entity inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this entity:

```
public class MyEntity : IMergeable<Entities.EntityExample>
{
    [Required]    
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Label{ get; set; }

    public System.DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
}
```

I want to replicate it in a ViewModel that will have a 4th property called DateEnd. I was thinking about doing this:

```
namespace MyNamespace.ViewModels
{
    public class ExampleViewModel
    {    
        public ExampleViewModel(MyEntity myEntity)
        {
            myentity = myEntity;
        }

        public myEntity myentity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DateEnd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works, but my problem is that my view model will be arranged in the following way:

```
myViewModel.myentity.Code
myViewModel.myentity.Label
myViewModel.myentity.DateStart
myViewModel.DateEnd
```

When what I really wanted was:

```
myViewModel.Code
myViewModel.Label
myViewModel.DateStart
myViewModel.DateEnd
```

Or at least (not so good):

```
myViewModel.myentity.Code
myViewModel.myentity.Label
myViewModel.myentity.DateStart
myViewModel.myentity.DateEnd
```

Comment: please consider https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose properties on your view model that just accesses the underlying entity property:

```
private myEntity _entity;

public DateTime DateStart {
    get { return _entity.DateStart; }
    set { _entity.DateStart = value; }        
}
```

But I would really just create a new view model and then use something like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or a plain factory to convert the view model to your entity. I guess this is repetitious but entity -> view model is the one place I've never worried about that.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
}

var entity = new myEntity { 
    Code = viewModel.Code,
    Label = viewModel.Label,
    DateStart = viewModel.DateStart
    ... dont know what you want to do with DateEnd
}
```

But then where and how do you handle validation? You have annotations on your entity so you could convert to the entity and then check the entity's validity but you'll lose validation on DateEnd since it's not a property on your entity. So I would add validation on the view model and check its validity before convert to an entity.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply inherit from your entity:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : MyEntity
{    
    [Required]
    public string DateEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will consider your approach.

Comment: Personally I prefer to keep my entities totally separate from my view models so I would be unlikely to do this. The comment from @tschmit007 suggestion to use AutoMapper is a much better idea even though it requires more effort.